# Add CMS block to bottom of each product list

Tags: layout, magento2.2, cms-block, category-listing

I would like to add a CMS block to the bottom of each product list whehter it is on a category page or the search result page. Since I would like to add it on every list I'll try to do this via layout customization within `default.xml` of my theme.

Unfortunatelly I'm not able to reference on the related container or block.

I'm able to add a block to the content container by using following code:

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
    <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="block_category_below_collection">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">block_category_below_collection</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
</referenceContainer>
```

But this show the cms_block on every page at the top, not only at th bottom of product lists. I tried other reference names like:

```
<referenceContainer name="category.products.list">
<referenceBlock name="category.products.list">
```

But I'm not sure which is the correct one and I'm not able to determine it by my self. Enabling template and block hints states that the template file is `/var/www/html/px.local/mage22/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/category/products.phtml` and the related block is `"Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\View"`.

But here I'm stuck.

Can anyone help to determine how to add the CMS block?

Comment: try to use after="-". So your block tag <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="block_category_below_collection" after="-">

Comment: Yes that fixed, that the CMS block is rendered at the top. Thank you. But my main issue is that I'll try to reference only to category product list and search result product list. In my example above I'm referancing to the content container which renders the CMS block to each page, including each CMS page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of:

```
<block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="block_category_below_collection">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">block_category_below_collection</argument>
    </arguments>
</block>
```

Try:

```
<block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="block_category_below_collection" after="-">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">block_category_below_collection</argument>
    </arguments>
</block>
```

Note the **`after="-"`** difference.

**Update:**
One more thing to notice is that you have used default.xml for the layout changes, which will add the layout update in all pages.

Please use it in **`catalog_category_view.xml`** and **`catalogsearch_result_index.xml`**.

Comment: Yes that fixed, that the CMS block is rendered at the top. Thank you. But my main issue is that I'll try to reference only to category product list and search result product list. In my example above I'm referancing to the content container which renders the CMS block to each page, including each CMS page.

Comment: Do not use your code in default.xml. Please use it in **`catalog_category_view.xml`** and **`catalogsearch_result_index.xml`**

Comment: That's the trick. I'm used to make those changes in the local.xml from Magento1. Thought the default.xml in Magento2 working the same way.

Comment: Also click on right symbol (accept my answer).

Answer (score 2):

You can try this solutuions.
first you need to update your **list.phtml** file path like :-

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml

Call Static block At the end of the file after toolbar. like this one :-

```
<?= $block->getToolbarHtml() ?>
<?php if (!$block->isRedirectToCartEnabled()) : ?>
    <script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "[data-role=tocart-form], .form.map.checkout": {
            "catalogAddToCart": {
                "product_sku": "<?= /* @NoEscape */ $_product->getSku() ?>"
            }
        }
    }
    </script>
<?php endif; ?>
 <?php endif; ?>
  /* this is my cms block */ 
  <?php echo $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Bloc\Block')->setBlockId('identifire')->toHtml();?>
```

i call static block at end of the file.

Comment: Yes that works, but I try to achieve this via layout customization without modifing template files. It is easier to maintain from my point of view.

Comment: Ok Thank you....

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Mohit for the hint. For anyone else who try to achive this, here is how I did it:

Copying `/root/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/layout/catalog_category_view.xml` to my custom child theme folder `/root/app/design/frontend/THEME_VENDOR/CHILD_THEME/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_category_view.xml`.
Opened the copied xml file and added my code within the `referenceContainer name="content"`:

```
<referenceContainer name="content">

.
.
.

  <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="MY-BLOCK-IDENTIFIER" after="-">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">MY-BLOCK-IDENTIFIER</argument>
    </arguments>
  </block>  
</referenceContainer>
```